# Indexing vertex name

Tags: python, igraph

I am using python igraph version 0.6.5. I am bit unclear that in a code below:

```
g = igraph.Graph(directed=True)
g.add_vertex('A')
g.add_vertex('B')
g.add_vertex('A')
print g.vcount()
```

This gives me the count of vertex as 3 even though the vertex name 'A' is duplicated , why both vertex name 'A' are taken as 2 different vertex ? How can we index the vertex name ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ' How can we index the vertex name ?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `g.add_vertex('A')`, igraph does *not* add `"A"` as a vertex to the graph - it adds a completely new vertex and then assigns `"A"` to its `name` attribute, but names are not required to be unique in igraph. Internally vertices are represented by integers from zero to |V|-1, and the names are just attributes that are attacked to the vertices. So, if you want to make sure that you don't create duplicate vertices with the same name, you need to check whether a vertex exists with the same name:

```
try:
    vertex = g.vs.find("A")
except ValueError:
    g.add_vertex("A")
```

The `name` vertex attribute is treated specially by igraph as it is always backed by a dictionary that maps vertex names to the *first* vertex that has this name, so `g.vs.find("A")` is a fast operation (no need to scan the entire graph).